# How to install rdkit with anaconda

Tags: python, conda, rdkit

I'm trying to install rdkit with

```
conda create -c rdkit -n my-rdkit-env rdkit
```

but when it's Downloading and Extracting Packages it's stopping! what should I do? I tried every command I found on the internet and none of them work!

Comment: What's the error it's giving before it crashes?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to install RDKit from conda's default channel as suggested by @MichalK's answer. Instead, I had to install from conda's `conda-forge` channel:

> conda install -c conda-forge rdkit

Another advantage of using the `conda-forge` channel is that it has more recent version (v2022.09.4 for linux-64) of RDKit than the default channel  (v2020.09.1.0 for linux-64).

conda version: 4.13.0

Answer (score 1):

```
conda install rdkit -c rdkit
```

If this doesn’t work, then something is wrong with your anaconda installation.